# gmaps4rails map not showing when loaded dynamically using prototype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs, rjs, gmaps4rails

I have a view with 3 tabs each representing a view of the data (Table, Map, Charts).
When I click on the tab it blinds up the view before if runs switch_view.js.rjs

```
<%= link_to_remote I18n.t('biomass_configuration_menu.button.view.table'), 
        :url =>{:controller => :biogas_calculator, :action => :switch_view, :view => "table"}, 
        :method => :get, 
        :loading => visual_effect(:blind_up, "biomass_configuration", :duration => 0.5, :queue => 'front'), 
        :html => {:id => "table_view", :class => "toggle_map_button"} %>

<%= link_to_remote I18n.t('biomass_configuration_menu.button.view.map'), 
        :url =>{:controller => :biogas_calculator, :action => :switch_view, :view => "map"}, 
        :method => :get, 
        :loading => visual_effect(:blind_up, "biomass_configuration", :duration => 0.5, :queue => 'front'), 
        :html => {:id => "map_view", :class => "toggle_map_button"} %>

<%= link_to_remote I18n.t('biomass_configuration_menu.button.view.charts'), 
        :url =>{:controller => :biogas_calculator, :action => :switch_view, :view => "charts"}, 
        :method => :get, 
        :loading => visual_effect(:blind_up, "biomass_configuration", :duration => 0.5, :queue => 'front'), 
        :html => {:id => "chart_view", :class => "toggle_map_button"} %>
```

When I click on the map tab I am running this:

In the HTML map view:

```
<%= gmaps(:map_options => { :id => "configuration_map", 
          :last_map => false },
          :markers => { "data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list" }}) %>
```

In my RJS (switch_view.js.rjs), biomass_configuration is the DIV the HTML presenting either a Table, a Map or Charts:

```
page.replace_html("biomass_configuration", :partial => "biomass_configuration")

page[:biomass_configuration].visual_effect :blind_down, :duration => 1

if session[:view] == "map"
      page.delay 3 do
         page << "Gmaps.loadMaps();"    <=== I thought this would do the trick
      end
end
```

When I click on the tabs, it correctly blinds up and down for the table view and the charts, but it still doesn't work with my map.

I figured I should put a delay after the blind down and before I call Gmaps.loadMaps() ... I tried playing with that delay without any chance.

If I reload the page Ctrl + R then the blind up and down seem to work correct.

I also tried setting :last_map => true with no success ...

Here the app http://biowattsonline.com

My application.js:

```
//= require prototype
//= require prototype_ujs
//= require effects
//= require dragdrop
//= require controls
//= require_tree .
//= require gmaps4rails/bing.js
//= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
//= require gmaps4rails/mapquest.js
//= require gmaps4rails/openlayers.js   
//= require gmaps4rails/all_apis.js
//= require facebox.js
//= require i18n
//= require i18n/translations
```

20121229 - WHAT I DID NEW to resolve the issue:

Instead of replacing the div biomass_configuration, I decided to load all 3 views and only show the one on a tab click. So the other DIVs are set with display:none.

I changed my tab buttons link_to_remote and my switch_view.rjs:

MY TAB BUTTONS:

```
<%= link_to_remote I18n.t('biomass_configuration_menu.button.view.table'), 
    :url =>{:controller => :biogas_calculator, :action => :switch_view, :view => "table"}, 
    :method => :get, 
    :loading => visual_effect(:fade, "biomass_configuration_charts", :duration => 1, :queue => 'front') +
                visual_effect(:fade, "biomass_configuration_map", :duration => 1, :queue => 'front'),
    :html => {:id => "table_view", :class => "toggle_map_button"} %>

<%= link_to_remote I18n.t('biomass_configuration_menu.button.view.map'), 
    :url =>{:controller => :biogas_calculator, :action => :switch_view, :view => "map"}, 
    :method => :get, 
    :before =>  visual_effect(:fade, "biomass_configuration_charts", :duration => 1, :queue => 'front') + 
                visual_effect(:fade, "biomass_configuration_table", :duration => 1, :queue => 'front'),
    :loading => visual_effect(:appear, "biomass_configuration_map", :duration => 1, :queue => 'end'), 
    :complete => 'Gmaps.loadMaps();' ,
    :html => {:id => "map_view", :class => "toggle_map_button"}  if logged_in? %>

<%= link_to_remote I18n.t('biomass_configuration_menu.button.view.charts'), 
    :url =>{:controller => :biogas_calculator, :action => :switch_view, :view => "charts"}, 
    :method => :get, 
    :loading  => visual_effect(:fade, "biomass_configuration_table", :duration => 1, :queue => 'front') + 
                 visual_effect(:fade, "biomass_configuration_map", :duration => 1, :queue => 'front'), 
    :html => {:id => "chart_view", :class => "toggle_map_button"} %>
```

and my RJS:

```
if  session[:view] == "map"
  #page[:biomass_configuration_map].visual_effect :appear
end

if  session[:view] == "table"
  page[:biomass_configuration_table].visual_effect :appear
end

if  session[:view] == "charts"
  page[:biomass_configuration_charts].visual_effect :appear
end
```

This time the map shows but in a corner. A problem I had before, but somehow the fix didn't work on that one.

20120101 - Added Goggle maps API library

In my layout:

```
<head>
  <%= render "layouts/tags" %>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=I_DID_PUT_MY_KEY_HERE&sensor=true">
  </script>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <%= render 'layouts/google_analytics' %>    
</head>
```

Loading Google maps api before the other libraries in application.js

Still Works on my development environment but not once deployed on Heroku.

20120103 Updates

HEADER page generated

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"/>
<script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/5/16/%7Bmain,geometry%7D.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.5/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"/>
<link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"/>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/5/16/%7Bcommon,util%7D.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome-extension://bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn/js/injected.js"/>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/5/16/%7Bcommon,util%7D.js"/>
</head>
```

FOOTER generated

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"/>
<script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/5/16/%7Bmain,geometry%7D.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.5/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

Gmaps.configuration_map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_configuration_map = function() {
Gmaps.configuration_map.map_options.detect_location = false;
Gmaps.configuration_map.map_options.center_on_user = false;
Gmaps.configuration_map.map_options.zoom = 0;
Gmaps.configuration_map.map_options.id = 'configuration_map';
Gmaps.configuration_map.map_options.last_map = false;
Gmaps.configuration_map.initialize();
Gmaps.configuration_map.markers = [{"description": "<div style='width:200px;'><p>Dec 13,2010 16:32 UTC</p> <h1 style='font-size:14px;' class=selling>SELLING</h1> <h2 style='font-size:12px;'><span style='color:#333;'>Lucerne gras, 2. cut, start flowering</span><sup style='font-size:9px;' class='cancelled state'>cancelled</sup></h2>  <p style='font-size:12px;'>2000 tons in Goma, Republique democratique du congo</p> Posted by <b><em>biowatts</em></b> </div>", "sidebar": "<span class='map_sidebar_item'><b>Lucerne gras, 2. cut, start flowering</b><br>2000 t/a</span>", "lng": "29.225241", "lat": "-1.693314"},{"description": "<div style='width:200px;'><p>Sep 17, 2011 23:43 UTC</p> <h1 style='font-size:14px;' class=wanted>WANTED</h1> <h2 style='font-size:12px;'><span style='color:#333;'>feeder cattle liquid manure</span><sup style='font-size:9px;' class='cancelled state'>cancelled</sup></h2>  <p style='font-size:12px;'>1000 tons in Rio de janeiro, Brasil</p> Posted by <b><em>biowatts</em></b> </div>", "sidebar": "<span class='map_sidebar_item'><b>feeder cattle liquid manure</b><br>1000 t/a</span>", "lng":"-43.2095869", "lat": "-22.9035393"},{"description": "<div style='width:200px;'><p>Sep 17, 2011 23:43 UTC</p> <h1 style='font-size:14px;' class=wanted>WANTED</h1> <h2 style='font-size:12px;'><span style='color:#333;'>Dummy</span><sup style='font-size:9px;' class='cancelled state'>cancelled</sup></h2>  <p style='font-size:12px;'>4000 tons in Sydney, Australia</p> Posted by <b><em>biowatts</em></b> </div>", "sidebar": "<span class='map_sidebar_item'><b>Dummy</b><br>4000 t/a</span>", "lng": "151.2070914", "lat": "-33.8689009"}];
Gmaps.configuration_map.markers_conf.list_container = 'markers_list';
Gmaps.configuration_map.create_markers();
Gmaps.configuration_map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.configuration_map.callback();
};
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); }; <=========== when :last_map => false 
</script>
```

Note the Gmaps.loadMaps despite :last_option => false ... I thought should happen only when :last_map option set to true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced this situation before and it's not related to `gmaps4rails`.

You have to:

- include all the js files in the page manually so that they are loaded properly when the page is loaded
- pass the proper option to the helper so that it doesn't try to include it again
- use `Gmaps.loadMaps()` as you already understood.

To sum up, it's just a question of js file loading.

---

Let's make things clear:

*Files to include in your html (I assume you use google maps):*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.5/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
```

*Files to include in your js manifest:*

```
//= require ./gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
```

As you already did, the google maps javascript must be added before the `application.js` file.

To make sure the gmaps4rails files are included in your app, you can run the generator to have them copied in your app: `rails generate gmaps4rails:install`. From there you can remove much of the files depending on the map API you use.

---

Change your call to the helper this way:

```
<%= gmaps(:map_options => { :id => "configuration_map" },
          :markers => { "data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list"     }},
          :scripts => :none,
          :last_map => false) %>
```

Sidenote:

You load the js file `http://maps.gstatic.com` twice but with different options, you could simply do:

```
 <script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/5/16/%7Bmain,geometry,common,util%7D.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Comment: Looks like I need more help on this one. I already spent hours I suspect that I don't know what I am doing. 1 - Include all js manually : today I am using application.js to load my js files ... does it mean that I'd need to include each file include in my layout file rather than loading the one application.js   2 - I don't what helper you may be referring too, is that visual_effect(...) is there a special option?   3 - I am puzzled the map loads correctly on my machine (dev) and it just doesn't work once deployed on Heroku ... hope you can help a little more. Thanks already.

Comment: I don't see any reference to the google maps libraries in your code. You need them!

Comment: I have * //= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js in application.js ... is this what you mean?

Comment: No, I really mean google maps services. I don't recall the url though.

Comment: Good reminder! unfortunately it doesn't sort out my issue. I edited my initial post with details of my layout <HEAD>

Comment: I suppose I need to set options[:map_options] ... but I don't with what. I am shameless :) I'll keep on trying and reading the doc until  then... but if you know I'd be grateful

Comment: I don't understand your latest comment. Sorry

Comment: Oh this is because I am getting an error: undefined local variable or method `options' from the first file include you suggested ... which contains libraries=geometry<%= g_libraries(options[:map_options].try(:[], :libraries)) %>  and that options hash that don't have ... so it fails

Comment: Still no success BUT I figured that I may be loading APIs twice or even thrice because of //= require gmaps4rails/all_apis.js that may be loading gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js again (do I guess correctly?) AND //= require_tree . that may be doing it once more (director ./gmaps4rails). So I removed these now... still the map appears in a corner. Which is better than no map. I assume NO map loading is a different issue. Now this only happens once deployed on Heroku. On my development environement, the maps in the corner adjusts to the full container after a second.

Comment: small correction, on my development env, the maps adjusts on the first time the maps loads :( so I don't think it's valid clue for the issue I have. It's all about the visual effects and that link_to_remote ... if I could I would work around that but I don't know how.

Comment: Just in case, I added (copied from firebug) the HEADER and FOOTER generated for my page in my original post. Looks like some libraries are loaded twice. In your first post you talk about passing the right option to the helper so it doesn't try to include. Which helper and how? Also looks like :last_map => false should have the effect of not calling Gmaps.loadMaps() on load window ... but it looks like it does in mine. Thanks for time you already spent on this.

Comment: I haven't been able to fix the problem completely but it does work a lot better and as a workaround the user can reload the page and it will work... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Give me the url where the map lives, we'll fix that.

Comment: Most Kind! Here http://test-biowatts.heroku.com  login with email test.biowatts(at)gmail.com and password:anaerobic Then Choose Dummy Farm ... there you repro the issue when Clicking on Map tab (Works!) then on Table tab and finally click again on the Map tab that's where the issue happens.

Comment: Just had a look. You should simply trigger: `Gmaps.loadMaps()` each time you display the map.

Comment: BTW, you have another js error: `Uncaught Error: Container is not defined`

Comment: I thought I was Calling Gmaps.loadMaps every time actually. How can debug whether it's actually done? Inspect Element, Firebug? (BTW I fixed that Uncaught error.)