# gmaps4rails map display

Tags: gmaps4rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am trying to use the gmaps4rails gem.  The longitude and latitude show up automatically but the map is not appearing.  If I look at the page source info it seems like the map is being called and created so I'm not sure why it's not showing up.
This can be seen here:

```
    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&amp;sensor=false&amp;client=&   amp;key=& amp;libraries=geometry&amp;language=&amp;hl=&amp;region=" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
      Gmaps.load_map = function() {
      Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_adjust = true;
      Gmaps.map.initialize();
      Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":40.8217303,"lng":-73.9551369},             {"lat":41.4925374,"lng":-99.9018131},{"lat":50.3429668,"lng":18.5540869}];
      Gmaps.map.markers_conf.do_clustering = true;
      Gmaps.map.create_markers();
      Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
      Gmaps.map.callback();
       };
```

Do I need to include some other files in my document to show the map?  And where would those documents be?  I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.12.
I see this type of question has been asked and answered many times, but I haven't been able to get a solution from those answers. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

Here is my view:

```
            <br />
            <%= link_to 'New Bathroom', new_bathroom_path %>
            <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

Model:

```
  acts_as_gmappable

      def gmaps4rails_address
      address
```

Controller:

```
    def index
     @bathrooms = Bathroom.all
  @json = Bathroom.all.to_gmaps4rails
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @bathrooms }
     end
     end
```

and application.html

```
       <%= yield %>
       <%= yield :scripts %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>

     </body>
    </html>
```

One thing I'm wondering is if I need to copy some assets to the app.  It says on the github site.

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
`gmaps4rails.css` will be copied to your app after you run the Rails generator. Be sure to require this file in your view for your first steps.

For Rails 3.0.x or without assets pipeline:

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

Since I don't see the gmaps4rails.css file I wonder if that's the problem.  Thanks for helping.

---

Post Debugger Details:

Yeah that's true.  I have almost no experience with this stuff.  I got Firebug as you recommended and discovered that when I glide over the page the google scripts in the debugger never get highlighted.  I see that it did try to make a call to googleapis.com But the time for the different actions are zero, except for blocking and waiting.  This makes me think nothing was sent from the google server.  Under Get gmaps4rails.css it looks in my app/asset folder and has a 404 error.  I'm learning how to understand all this info, and if I'm correct it seems like the server request to google was blocked for some reason and it thinks my css file is in the asset folder.  If I am correct I really have no idea where to go from here.  Please tell me what info would help make this problem clearer.

Comment: Please show us the entire view. I have a feeling that you are not including something.

Comment: Thanks I just added the info under Update.

Comment: The CSS not being there could definitely be it, but are you sure it is not there? Have checked the generated HTML source in the browser?

Comment: The CSS is definitely there since it's generated in html.  I tried adding some size modifications as it seems that solved some people's problems.  But I had to add the size modifications in the scaffold.css.scss file.  This gave me a blank map with no image when I added the .map_container and .gmaps4rails_map  classes.  I'm wondering if there's something I can add to this file to make the actual map appear.  Thanks again!

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn a bit more about HTML/CSS debugging. If you are using Chrome or Safari look into using the Web Inspector and if you are on Firefox look in to Firebug. This will allow you to look at the individual HTML elements and see what styles are being/not being applied to an element. It will also show if there are any errors in loading stylesheets/scripts/etc. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Thanks I added some more details under above under post debugger details.

Comment: First thing first. Where is your CSS actually located if it isn't in the assets folder?

Comment: The only css that seems to have been read is the scaffold.css.scss...  Is it true that the gamps4rails.css is grabbed from the google server?

Comment: No, the css should be in your stylesheets folder.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this.  As it turns out the problem lies in a misunderstanding of this instruction: `"gmaps4rails.css` will be copied to your app after you run the Rails generator. Be sure to require this file in your view for your first steps."  Being new I thought after I generated the scaffolding the gmaps4rails gem would automatically generate the css.  Anyhow, this answer helped: site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578681/gmaps4rails-map-not-showing-when-loaded-dynamically-using-prototype  There it says type "rails generate gmaps4rails:install"

Comment: No problem! Glad it seems to be working out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run 'rails generate gmaps4rails:install'. That will supply the missing bits (and the css will be sourced automatically in rails 3.2).

After that, you should be good to go (based on the original question, and barring any subsequent changes).